# Parse nested JSON with variable length

Tags: android, json

Here is my JSON.Tell me a way to parse this using JSON.org.I'm able to parse till photpath.How to proceed further and I want to check "Hascomment" field and then proceed to "comments" array.How to do this?

```
{
"success":1,
"complaints":[
{
"complaintID":"1",
"userName":"Ganesh ",
"Title":"Check HelloMLA ",
"Description":"This is to check HelloMLA app after finishing image upload and download ",
"DOS":"02\/18\/15 21:14",
"Ago":"5 days ago",
"Status":"SOLVED",
"Photopath":"MLA\/images\/complaints\/1\/IMG_20141117_125245.jpg",
"Hascomment":"3",
"comments":[]
},
{
"complaintID":"2",
"userName":"Ganesh ",
"Title":"Check HelloMLA 2",
"Description":"This is to check HelloMLA app after finishing image upload and download 2",
"DOS":"02\/18\/15 21:14",
"Ago":"5 days ago",
"Status":"ANSWERED",
"Photopath":"MLA\/images\/complaints\/2\/IMG_20140806_120618.jpg",
"Hascomment":"1",
"comments":[]
},
{
"complaintID":"3",
"userName":"Ganesh ",
"Title":"Check HelloMLA 3",
"Description":"This is to check HelloMLA app after finishing image upload and download 3",
"DOS":"02\/18\/15 21:16",
"Ago":"5 days ago",
"Status":"UNSOLVED",
"Photopath":"MLA\/images\/complaints\/3\/IMG_20140808_121345.jpg",
"Hascomment":"0"
},
{
"complaintID":"4",
"userName":"Ganesh ",
"Title":"Check HelloMLA 4",
"Description":"This is to check HelloMLA app after finishing image upload and download ",
"DOS":"02\/18\/15 21:16",
"Ago":"5 days ago",
"Status":"UNSOLVED",
"Photopath":"MLA\/images\/complaints\/4\/IMG_20140820_175353.jpg",
"Hascomment":"0"
},
{
"complaintID":"28",
"userName":"Ganesh ",
"Title":"hello Gurudaths",
"Description":"Gurudaths93 is default email",
"DOS":"02\/21\/15 12:29",
"Ago":"3 days ago",
"Status":"UNSOLVED",
"Photopath":"MLA\/images\/complaints\/28\/IMG-20141205-WA0010.jpg",
"Hascomment":"0"
},
{
"complaintID":"35",
"userName":"Ganesh ",
"Title":"hello how r u",
"Description":"Naanu fine Neenu",
"DOS":"02\/23\/15 5:41",
"Ago":"1 day ago",
"Status":"UNSOLVED",
"Photopath":"MLA\/images\/complaints\/35\/Brain-erasure-300x225.jpg",
"Hascomment":"0"
},
{
"complaintID":"36",
"userName":"Ganesh ",
"Title":"fhj ajji ",
"Description":"hjhvcf chjj chhbji ",
"DOS":"02\/23\/15 5:42",
"Ago":"1 day ago",
"Status":"UNSOLVED",
"Photopath":null,
"Hascomment":"0"
}
]
}
```

Comment: can you post what until you have tried , so that we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the *complaints* key has an array of objects. Each object has item e.g. *complaintID*, *userName*, *Title*, etc. You can get the value of *complaints* in a [JSONArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html). Then loop through the *JSONArray* and get each object in [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) using [length()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#length%28%29). You can then access all the items from the *JSONObject*. *JSONObject* class has a method [has(String name)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has%28java.lang.String%29) which you can use to check whether an item exist in a *JSONObject* before getting its value.

**Pseudo code:**

```
        if(jsonObject.has("success")) {
            try {
                Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(jsonObject.getInt("success")));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if(jsonObject.has("complaints")) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("complaints");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); ++i) {
                    JSONObject jsonChildObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    if(jsonChildObject.has("complaintID")) {
                        Log.d("TAG", jsonChildObject.getString("complaintID"));
                    }
                    if(jsonChildObject.has("userName")) {
                        Log.d("TAG", jsonChildObject.getString("userName"));
                    }

//                  .
//                  .
//                  .
//                  .
//                  .
//                  .

                    if(jsonChildObject.has("Photopath") && jsonChildObject.getString("Photopath") != null) {
                        Log.d("TAG", jsonChildObject.getString("Photopath"));
                    }
                    if(jsonChildObject.has("Hascomment")) {
                        Log.d("TAG", jsonChildObject.getString("Hascomment"));
                    }
                    if(jsonChildObject.has("comments")) {
                        JSONArray jsonCommentArray = jsonChildObject.getJSONArray("comments");
                        for (int j = 0; j < jsonCommentArray.length(); ++j) {
//                          Print comments using index as j.
                        }
                    }

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```